# pyspark error: "object has no attribute '_get_object_id' " when trying to read file

Tags: python, pyspark

I have the following code for reading in files from a folder:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
spark = SparkSession(sc)

class MicrosoftAcademicGraph:

 def __init__(self):
  self.version = '2021-12-06'
  
 def getBasepath(self):
    basepath = '/work/ScienceOfScience/Data/ScienceOfScience/mag/mag/'
    if (self.version != ''):
      basepath = self.version + '/'
    return basepath

  # return stream path
 def getFullpath(self, streamName):
    path = self.getBasepath() + self.streams[streamName][0]
    return self

  # return stream header
 def getHeader(self, streamName):
    return self.streams[streamName][1]


  # return stream schema
 def getSchema(self, streamName):
    schema = StructType()
    for field in self.streams[streamName][1]:
      fieldname, fieldtype = field.split(':')
      nullable = fieldtype.endswith('?')
      if nullable:
        fieldtype = fieldtype[:-1]
      schema.add(StructField(fieldname, self.datatypedict[fieldtype], nullable))
    return schema

  # return stream dataframe
 def getDataframe(self, streamName):
    return spark.read.format('csv').options(header='false', delimiter='\t').schema(self.getSchema(streamName)).load(self.getFullpath(streamName))

  # define stream dictionary
 streams = {
    'Affiliations' : ('mag/Affiliations.txt', ['AffiliationId:long', 'Rank:uint', 'NormalizedName:string', 'DisplayName:string', 'GridId:string', 'OfficialPage:string', 'WikiPage:string', 'PaperCount:long', 'PaperFamilyCount:long', 'CitationCount:long', 'Iso3166Code:string', 'Latitude:float?', 'Longitude:float?', 'CreatedDate:DateTime']),
    'AuthorExtendedAttributes' : ('mag/AuthorExtendedAttributes.txt', ['AuthorId:long', 'AttributeType:int', 'AttributeValue:string'])}
```

I'm tring to retrieve one of the files called 'Authors' in the following way:

e = MicrosoftAcademicGraph()
e.getDataframe('Authors')

I get a long list of errors that look like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 51, in getDataframe
  File "/home/ucloud/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 162, in load
    return self._df(self._jreader.load(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
  File "/home/ucloud/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1313, in __call__
    args_command, temp_args = self._build_args(*args)
  File "/home/ucloud/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1277, in _build_args
    (new_args, temp_args) = self._get_args(args)
    command_part = REFERENCE_TYPE + parameter._get_object_id()
AttributeError: 'MicrosoftAcademicGraph' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'

is there something wrong in the code or does this maybe have to do with version mismatch between python and pyspark?
```

Comment: This error can occur in many situations so it is hard to pinpoint where this error is occurring, however, I see something odd.  `getDataframe` is calling `getSchema` and within `getSchema`, it is referencing the `streams` by the key name you are passing. Although I am not seeing "Authors" in the dict.   Could you check if you can do `e.getDataframe('Affiliations')`?

Comment: thanks! sorry, I actually have "Authors" defined in the streams as well I just cut it out because the site didn't let me post that much code, but e.getDataframe('Affiliations') gives the same error. this is all the code I have so if the code itself looks fine then it must be some problem with the version of python and pyspark I'm using?

Comment: I see. yeah, that could be possible.  I would also try narrowing down the issue.  
For example, do you see errors if you just do `spark.read.format('csv').load(self.getFullpath(streamName))`?  Or printing out `self.getFullpath(streamName)` and `self.getSchema(streamName)`, and see if everything looks correct.

Comment: spark.read.format('csv').load(self.getFullpath(streamName)) works if I replace 'self.getFullpath(streamName)' with the directory! I'm not sure how to call  self.getFullpath(streamName) because it says NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: sounds like it is something in the path function. getting closer!  try `e.getFullpath(streamName)` where you instantiate the class.

Comment: Oh i see it.  The `getFullpath` is returning the `self`.  Do you mean to return `path`?

Comment: oh I see it has "return self" instead of "return path". that fixed it, it works now! thank you.